# prepend key to javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am receiving data filled in from a form, but before posting to the server I need to prepend a key

```
> data
Object {rate: "300", identifier: "ZDA"}
```

Then I need to generate a unique key such as `"OTNmam1JUkM="`. The key is generated from a function like:

```
key = generateKey();
```

and prepend it to the object so I end up with

```
Object {"OTNmam1JUkM=": {rate: "300", identifier: "ZDA"}}
```

Any help would be appreciated... Please note I am using angular in an Ionic cross platform app.

Comment: you have to call encodeURIComponent on each attribute of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newData = {};
newData[generateKey()] = data;
```

You can use expressions when use with [].

Answer (score 0):

You don't mean prepend, but to nest it:

```
var data = {rate: "300", identifier: "ZDA"}; // or whatever you get from the form
var key = generateKey();
var nested = {};
nested[key] = data;
console.log(nested);
```

This will print out: `{"OTNmam1JUkM=": {rate: "300", identifier: "ZDA"}}`

Comment: Your example seems to work... but I need to do something more like `{key:data}` where `var key = generateKey()` and data is passed from the form

Comment: I renamed the variables, maybe that helps you to understand. Or I don't understand something, in which case try to explain what do you still miss

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple like:

```
var key = generateKey();
var oldData = data;
data = {};
data[key] = oldData;
```

---

See it here:

```js
var data = {rate: "300", identifier: "ZDA"};
var key = generateKey();
var oldData = data;
data = {};
data[key] = oldData;

function generateKey() {
  return 'iAmRandomISwear';
}

alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```